# ASP.NET MVC Viewmodel returns nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

Trying to make a simple application but my view returns nothing when trying to use a viewmodel. I assume the "db.[TableName].ToList();", which works when applied on a domain model, is not enough and the selection should happen in a different way when using a viewmodel, but I have no idea how to do it. Please help. Thank you.

**Town.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace City.Models
{
    public class Town
    {
        public Town()
        {
            Streets = new List<Street>();
        }
        public int TownId { get; set; }
        public string TownName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Street.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace City.Models
{
    public class Street
    {
        public Street()
        {
            Houses = new List<House>();
        }
        public int StreetId { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<House> Houses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**House.cs**

```
namespace City.Models
{
    public class House
    {
        public int HouseId { get; set; }
        public string HoueseName { get; set; }
        public int StreetId { get; set; }
        public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Floor.cs**

```
namespace City.Models
{
    public class Floor
    {
        public int FloorId { get; set; }
        public int FloorNumber { get; set; }
        public int FireExtinguisherId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**FireExtinguisher.cs**

```
namespace City.Models
{
    public class FireExtinguisher
    {
        public int FireExtinguisherId { get; set; }
        public string FireExtinguisherName { get; set; }
        public int FloorId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
namespace City.Models
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Town = new Town();
            Street = new Street();
            House = new House();
            Floor = new Floor();
            FireExtinguisher = new FireExtinguisher();
        }

        public int MyViewModelId { get; set; }
        public Town Town { get; set; }
        public Street Street { get; set; }
        public House House { get; set; }
        public Floor Floor { get; set; }
        public FireExtinguisher FireExtinguisher { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Town> Towns { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Street> Streets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<House> Houses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FireExtinguisher> FireExtinguishers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MyViewModel> MyViewModels { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

**HomeController.cs** (I think the problem lies here)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using City.Models;

namespace City.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db;
        public HomeController()
        {
            db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.MyViewModels.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<City.Models.MyViewModel>

<h2>Map information</h2>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Town</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>House</th>
                <th>Floor</th>
                <th>FireExtinguisher</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@(item.Town.TownName)</td>
                    <td>@(item.Street.StreetName)</td>
                    <td>@(item.House.HoueseName)</td>
                    <td>@(item.Floor.FloorNumber)</td>
                    <td>@(item.FireExtinguisher.FireExtinguisherName)</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Even though I have test data in the db, this is all what I see when I run it:

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7IRp.jpg)

Please tell me what should I fix, how to get data retrieved. Thanks

**EDIT @CrowdCoder**

[new picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpbpe.jpg)

Comment: I don't think you are using the proper conventions for Entity Framework. You are newing up everything in the constructor of `MyViewModel` and I don't think your structure creates the correct navigation properties. However, it has been a while since I used EF. In your controller separate this line into a variable so you can break on it and look at its value `db.MyViewModels.ToList()` (also, you should not need to ToList() this)

Comment: I tried but it broke without ToList(). edited my post, please see changes

Comment: You can help diagnose your problem as EF related or not by returning a hard-coded view model in your controller instead of calling into the database. Just for testing, manually create some `MyViewModel`s and see if your view displays them.

Comment: hc-ing some values works, so the problem is definitely in querying the db - but this is kinda not very surprising as I was pretty sure since the beginning there's something wrong about the selection with data. my question is more like what is the right LINQ syntax to retrieve data from db when using viewmodels.

Comment: That's what I thought. You change or ask a new question focusing on EF and eliminate all the MVC stuff. I'm pretty sure it is that your classes do not conform to the EF conventions but someone more expert can help you better.

Comment: okay thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding about view model is incorrect.

View model is a class to transfer data between your view and your action method. **View model is specific to the view**. So if your view needs to display only 2 properties (`Name` and `Age`), your view model will have only those 2 properties. No need to bring all the properties from your entity model to the view model class.

I see that you added a new collection to the your db context,

```
public DbSet<MyViewModel> MyViewModels { get; set; }
```

This does not makes any sense. As i mentioned earlier, view models are UI concerns. It should not be in your data access code. Also do not mix the entities created by your ORM layer in your view model.

Also view models are simple POCOs. It should be  lean-flat classes with properties. It is your responsibility to load the property values. You can do that in your action method or another method called from your action method.

Let's say you want to display a list of houses with it's street name, you will create a view model like this

```
public class HouseViewModel
{
   public int HouseId { set; get;}
   public string HoueseName { set;get;}
   public string StreetName { set;get; }
}
```

Now in your view, you simply access these properties

```
@model IEnumerable<HouseViewModel>
<table>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
         <td>@item.HouseId </td>
         <td>@item.HoueseName </td>
         <td>@item.StreetName </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Ofcourse, for this code to work, you need to make sure you will be creating a list of `HouseViewModel` and send it to the view from your action method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var list= new List<HouseViewModel>{
               new HouseViewModel { HouseId =1,HoueseName ="Abc", StreetName ="Detroit"},
               new HouseViewModel { HouseId =2,HoueseName ="Xyz", StreetName ="Novi"}
   };
   return View(list);
}
```

Now you can see that how we are **using view model to transfer data from the action method to the view**. Here we just hard coded the property values for the items in the list we are sending. We can update that to read from your EF db context as needed.

Let's read all the Houses, use LINQ projection to create a `HouseViewModel` object for each item in that collection and assign the property values.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var houses = db.Houses
                  .Select(a=>new HouseViewModel 
                                  { HouseId =a.HouseId,
                                    HoueseName =a.HouseName,
                                    StreetName = a.Street.StreetName
                                  })
                  .ToList();
   return View(houses);
}
```

Comment: While it might be poor design, there is no law against using the same classes in your context as in your view model, so that is not causing the reported problem. Also, notice the model's properties are other Types, not strings so there is a need to wire up navigation properties.

Comment: "We can update that to read from your EF db context as needed." - yes, this is actually the whole point of my question. as I already pointed it out above, hc-ing values is a working solution but obviously this is not what I want but to fetch them from db. As for your recommendation for the VM changes, thank you, I'll do as advised. So how can I associate VM properties with domain model properties if VM is not a DB entity? How can I get back data from the DB?

Comment: I just updated the code to show you how to read from your db context and map that to the view model objects. Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Crowcoder ofcourse there is no laws. IMHO, view models should not be mixed with your data access layer. What if tomorrow you decided to change EF for performance reasons and switch to another tech ?  I prefer to do this way. But hey, it is me. You are welcome to do a different way.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, you just are not solving the problem so I would not consider this an answer.

Comment: thanks for the edit, but this is still not really what I need. That's cool we can retrieve houses or any other entity from the db but if I wanted to get back only one class at once, I wouldn't bother to have a VM but used the DM instead. The point of using a VM is to have multiple properties from multiple domain models at once. Therefore, just fetching houses (or any other stuff) own it's own is not really helping here.

Comment: Sure. You are free to express your opinion and i am free to share mine. It is a free world.

Comment: @Riwi **The point of using a VM is to have multiple properties from multiple domain models at once.** No. The point of using a VM is to seperate your UI concern from your data access layer / other layers.

Comment: yes, technically you are right. still, I need to focus on the side benefit of this technique of having multiple properties from multiple domain models in one model.