# ASP.NET MVC Viewmodel Edit returns empty fields (item is not identified by id)

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewmodel, edit

I previously reveived some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377582/asp-net-mvc-viewmodel-returns-nothing) but some problems with the "Edit" arouse now. Currently stuck at HttpGet, HttpPost is yet to come.

In short, whenever I click on an existing item to edit, instead of the expected values, it returns an empty form, [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI9J8.jpg). (You might think that the reason for this is because I use the same exact view for Create and Edit but unfortunately this isn't, even when I used to separate ones, had the same result.)

Town.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace City.Models
{
    public class Town
    {
        public Town()
        {
            Streets = new List<Street>();
        }
        public int TownId { get; set; }
        public string TownName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Street.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace City.Models
{
    public class Street
    {
        public Street()
        {
            Houses = new List<House>();
        }
        public int StreetId { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<House> Houses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

House.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace City.Models
{
    public class House
    {
        public House()
        {
            Floors = new List<Floor>();
        }
        public int HouseId { get; set; }
        public string HouseName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Floor.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace City.Models
{
    public class Floor
    {
        public Floor()
        {
            FireExtinguishers = new List<FireExtinguisher>();
        }
        public int FloorId { get; set; }
        public int FloorNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FireExtinguisher> FireExtinguishers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FireExtinguisher.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace City.Models
{
    public class FireExtinguisher
    {
        public int FireExtinguisherId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Fire Extinguisher")]
        public string FireExtinguisherName { get; set; }
        public int FloorId { get; set; }
        public int HouseId { get; set; }
        public int StreetId { get; set; }
        public int TownId { get; set; }
        public Floor Floor { get; set; }
        public House House { get; set; }
        public Street Street { get; set; }
        public Town Town { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace City.Models
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Town> TownId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Street> StreetId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<House> HouseId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Floor> FloorId { get; set; }
        public FireExtinguisher FireExtinguisher { get; set; }
        public string FireExtinguisherName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Create/Edit view

```
@model City.Models.MyViewModel

<h2>Add new or edit existing FE</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TownId, "Town", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TownId, new SelectList(Model.TownId, "TownId", "TownName"), "Choose Town", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TownId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StreetId, "Street", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StreetId, new SelectList(Model.StreetId, "StreetId", "StreetName"), "Choose Street", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StreetId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HouseId, "House", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HouseId, new SelectList(Model.HouseId, "HouseId", "HouseName"), "Choose House", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FloorId, "Floor", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FloorId, new SelectList(Model.FloorId, "FloorId", "FloorNumber"), "Choose Floor", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FloorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FireExtinguisherName, "Fire Extinguisher", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FireExtinguisherName, new { @class = "form-control", Value = "" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FireExtinguisherName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Do it" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Homecontroller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using City.Models;

namespace City.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db;
        private MyViewModel viewModel;

        public HomeController()
        {
            db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var town = db.Towns.ToList();
            var street = db.Streets.ToList();
            var house = db.Houses.ToList();
            var floor = db.Floors.ToList();

            viewModel = new MyViewModel()
            {
                TownId = town,
                StreetId = street,
                HouseId = house,
                FloorId = floor
            };
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.FireExtinguishers.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FireExtinguisher fe)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.FireExtinguishers.Add(fe);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var fe = db.FireExtinguishers.Find(id);

            var town = db.Towns.ToList();
            var street = db.Streets.ToList();
            var house = db.Houses.ToList();
            var floor = db.Floors.ToList();

            viewModel = new MyViewModel()
            {
                FireExtinguisher = fe,

                TownId = town,
                StreetId = street,
                HouseId = house,
                FloorId = floor
            };
            return View("Create", viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Do you mean the fire extinguisher name is empty? That's the only field I could see you might expect to be set, but the way you've written it currently it needs to be set explicitly (just setting the `FireExtinguisher` property isn't enough). But it's a very odd view model.

Comment: not only the FE name is empty, but all the fields are, as you can see on the picture link description on the top of the post. I expected all the values to retrieve through the FE. how would you improve the VM?

Comment: Why are your fields enumerables? Of course, if you link an enumerable, the field can not be filled. What would it be filled with? You have a whole list of items, which items should it take? And where would the selected item be stored in?

Comment: fields are enums because I intend to use dropdownlists in the view, as you can see in the Create/Edit view. I'm pretty sure it can be filled on Edit this way, I've seen this practice working before, just not sure how to make it myself. the returned value was identified by the id.

Comment: Yeah, but you need two properties. One with the collection of possible values and a second with the current selected value

Comment: yes, this is what I'm trying to achieve :) how to do this?

Comment: "Empty from" what do you mean that "empty form"? do the dropbox have items? Suppose that the form was not empty? how does the form look like?

Comment: @Riwi "How to do this?" => use your keyboard and type

Comment: Dan, the form exactly looks like as you can see it on the link provided on the top of the post. thanks :)

Comment: @Sir Rufo, are you sure this is the way? wouldn't it be better trying to control it with my mind?

Comment: Well you asked me how to have two properties. By using the keyboard and type some code for properties. I do that nearly every day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I like to use View- and Post-Models for that as a clear statement, what is send to the View (ViewModel) and what is send back via Post. As a naming convention the name of the model class Takes the controller name and the action name.

I start with the PostModel, which would be in your case

```
public class HomeEditPostModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TownId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StreetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int FloorId { get; set; }
}
```

Now for the view we need some collections for the dropdown fields, where we can select from

```
public class SelectionItem<TKey>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class HomeEditViewModel : HomeEditPostModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectionItem<int>> Town { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectionItem<int>> Street { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectionItem<int>> House { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectionItem<int>> Floor { get; set; }
}
```

Now the view

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.HomeEditViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>HomeEditSubmitModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TownId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TownId, new SelectList(Model.Town, "Key", "DisplayName"), "Choose Town", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TownId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StreetId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StreetId, new SelectList(Model.Street, "Key", "DisplayName"), "Choose Street", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StreetId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HouseId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HouseId, new SelectList(Model.House, "Key", "DisplayName"), "Choose House", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FloorId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FloorId, new SelectList(Model.Floor, "Key", "DisplayName"), "Choose Floor", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FloorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and finally the controller (only relevant parts)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // just some fake data for demonstration
        var model = new HomeEditViewModel
        {
            Name = "Name",
            Floor = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(e => new SelectionItem<int> { Key = e, DisplayName = $"Floor {e}" }),
            Street = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(e => new SelectionItem<int> { Key = e, DisplayName = $"Street {e}" }),
            House = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(e => new SelectionItem<int> { Key = e, DisplayName = $"House {e}" }),
            Town = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(e => new SelectionItem<int> { Key = e, DisplayName = $"Town {e}" }),

            FloorId = 3,
            StreetId = 4,
            HouseId = 5,
            TownId = 6,
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, HomeEditPostModel model)
    {
        // needs to save the data here

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, this seems to be clear and concise. have no opportunity to test it at the moment but will do tonight. I'll mark this as the accepted answer. thanks for your help @Sir Rufo